# regex inside a sed command

Tags: regex, sed, sh

I am having a little problem with putting a regex inside a sed command, this is my code:

```
RAW_LIST_B=`echo $RAW_LIST_A | sed s/[0-9a-f]{8} / /g`
```

And i get this error :

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 13: unterminated `s' command
```

I am not sure how to quote the `[0-9a-f]{8}` so that it removes all 8 digit hex numbers and trailing space from `RAW_LIST_A`

Thanks,

Comment: Could you also provide sample value for $RAW_LIST_A string/variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enclose sed experssion into a quotes so it will be one string parameter passed to sed by shell

```
RAW_LIST_B=`echo $RAW_LIST_A | sed "s/[0-9a-f]\{8\} //g"`
```

Sample output:

```
$ echo "hello a5a5a5a6 world" | sed "s/[0-9a-f]\{8\} //g"
hello world
```

Comment: No Effect, I suspect this is looking for literally "[0-9a-f]{8}". - No error though!

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
RAW_LIST_B=`echo $RAW_LIST_A | sed 's/[0-9a-f]\{8\} / /g'`
```

Since you did not quote the argument to `sed`, the shell splitted it into three arguments: `s/[0-9a-f]{8}`, `/` and `/g` before passing it to `sed`.

Also, note the backslashes to escape the curly brackets.

Comment: No Effect, I suspect this is looking for literally "[0-9a-f]{8}". - No error though!

Comment: Uh, I assumed you are looking for a literal `{8}`. If this is supposed to be "number of times the `[0-9a-f]` atom is repeated", then in `sed`, you need to escape it with backslashes. See the updated answer.